# SQL: Reducing select criteria when WHERE statement not true

Tags: sql, sql-server

Maybe not the most descriptive subject line, but the question is, whilst this query below does exactly what I'm after, I would also like to return records when Note.Name = 'Travel Advisory' is NOT true.
HOWEVER, when there is no Note.Name that equals 'Travel Advisory' I would still like the select values to be returned EXCEPT for Note.Notes.

The Note.Name column has various values such as 'Travel Advisory', 'General Information' and 'Guide'.

```
SELECT Supplier.Name, Supplier.Changeoverday, Supplier.Code, Note.Notes
FROM Supplier
INNER JOIN Note
ON Supplier.ID=Note.LINKID
WHERE Supplier.TID = 315
AND
Supplier.SID = 2350
AND
Note.Name = 'Travel Advisory'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT Supplier.Name, Supplier.Changeoverday, Supplier.Code, Note.Notes
FROM Supplier
LEFT JOIN Note
    ON Supplier.ID=Note.LINKID
    AND Note.Name = 'Travel Advisory'
WHERE Supplier.TID = 315
AND
Supplier.SID = 2350
```

If there is no matching record in the `Note` table then `Notes` will be `null`.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks so much for your help. Left Join!

Answer (score 0):

Edit:  I didn't notice you were selecting from 2 tables, I'd agree with the `OUTER JOIN` method that the other poster answered with. My way is a handy way to do it against 1 table (if you don't use table aliasing and an `OUTER JOIN`, that is...)

You can use a case to select the column and do what you want, just remove the part from the WHERE.  I think this syntax is good...

```
   SELECT 
    Supplier.Name
    , Supplier.Changeoverday
    , Supplier.Code
    , CASE WHEN Note.Notes = 'Travel Advisory' THEN Note.Notes ELSE 'Not Travel Advisory' END

    FROM Supplier
    INNER JOIN Note
    ON Supplier.ID=Note.LINKID
    WHERE Supplier.TID = 315
    AND
    Supplier.SID = 2350
```

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason this returns "Not Travel Advisory" for all records.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a `LEFT JOIN` to return `NULL` when there is no match, and a `SELECT CASE` to decide which value of Note.Notes to return in case of `Note.Name = 'Travel Advisory'`

```
SELECT Supplier.Name, Supplier.Changeoverday, Supplier.Code, 
       case when Note.Name = 'Travel Advisory' then '0' else Note.Notes END as Notes
FROM Supplier
LEFT JOIN Note
    ON Supplier.ID=Note.LINKID
WHERE Supplier.TID = 315
AND
Supplier.SID = 2350
```

However, if you want to return the rows for which the condition Note.Name =  'Travel Advisory' is `TRUE, False or UNKNOWN`,  I would also remove the filter on the same column (`Note.Name = 'Travel Advisory'`) .